# sed - Include newline in pattern

Tags: regex, shell, sed, cygwin

I am still a noob to shell scripts but am trying hard. Below, is a partially working shell script which is supposed to remove all JS from *.htm documents by matching  tags and deleting their enclosed content. E.g. `<script src="">`, `<script></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript">`

```
find $1 -name "*.htm" > ./patterns
for p in $(cat ./patterns)
do
sed -e "s/<script.*[.>]//g" $p #> tmp.htm ; mv tmp.htm $p
done
```

The problem with this is script is that because sed reads text input line-by-line, this script will not work as expected with new-lines. Running:

```
<script>
//Foo
</script>
```

will remove the first script tag but will omit the "foo" and closing  tag which I don't want.

Is there a way to match new-line characters in my regular expression? Or if `sed` is not appropriate, is there anything else I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you have `<script>` tags on different lines, e.g. something like:

```
foo
bar
<script type="text/javascript">
some JS
</script>
foo
```

the following should work:

```
sed '/<script/,/<\/script>/d' inputfile
```

Comment: Tested. It works. The only problem that I have with it is that characters on the same line are replaced along with the script tag. e.g.
foo<script>
foo

will result in just foo.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` script will look for the `<script*>` tag, set the `in` variable and then read the next line. When the closing `</script*>` tag is found the variable is set to zero. The final print pattern outputs all lines if the `in` variable is zero.

```
awk '/<script.*>/   { in=1; next }
     /<\/script.*>/ { if (in) in=0; next }
    { if (!in) print; } ' $1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the issue is that `sed` processes input line by line.

The simplest workaround is therefore to make the input a single line, e.g. replacing newlines with a character which you are confident doesn't exist in your input.

One would be tempted to use `tr` :

```
… |tr '\n' '_'|sed 's~<script>.*</script>~~g'|tr '_' '\n'
```

However "[currently `tr` fully supports only single-byte characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tr-invocation.html#tr-invocation)", and to be safe you probably want to use some improbable character like `ˇ`, for which `tr` is of no help.

Fortunately, the same thing can be achieved with `sed`, [using branching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/812102).

Back on our `<script>…</script>` example, this does work and would be (according to the previous link) cross-platform :

```
… |sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ˇ/g' -e 's~<script>.*</script>~~g' -e 's/ˇ/\n/g'
```

Or in a more condensed form if you use GNU `sed` and don't need cross-platform compatibility :

```
… |sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ˇ/g;s~<script>.*</script>~~g;s/ˇ/\n/g'
```

Please refer to the linked answer under "using branching" for details about the branching part (`:a;N;$!ba;`).  The remaining part is straightforward :

- `s/\n/ˇ/g` replaces all newlines with `ˇ` ;
- `s~<script>.*</script>~~g` removes what needs to be removed (beware that it requires some securing for actual use : as is it will delete everything between the first `<script>` and the last `</script>` ; also, note that I used `~` instead of `/` to avoid escaping of the slash in `</script>` : I could have used just about any single-byte character except a few reserved ones like `\`) ;
- `s/ˇ/\n/g` readds newlines.

Comment: Note that if you need to perform operations which do not depend on the branching, it may be wiser to pipe `sed` output to a new `sed` instance (I myself encountered issues with some operations working within the same instance, others not).